# How to decline a job offer in writing

Tags: professionalism, hiring-process

How can I politely decline a job offer from an employer in writing? What are the factors I should consider?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Keep it short, keep it to the point, keep it humble.

Say that you're not going to pursue the position because you've had an offer you can't refuse from elsewhere (do not tell them where or what, unless you want them to compete). Apologise and thank them for time and anything else they've spent giving you an opportunity to present yourself. Wish them good luck in finding the right candidate.

That's really all it takes.

I've received a few of these in my time and sent a couple too. There has never been any hard feelings.

Comment: I agree it doesn't have to be long. You are telling them in a few sentences that you have selected another offer. This stops them from wasting time waiting for you to respond to their offer letter.

Comment: I agree.  I question the premise of sending the letter through the mail.  The formality will not be appreciated.  It seems easier for everyone concerned to do it through email.

Comment: Thanks folks.I have drafted my mail based on the above points.Appreciate your help.

Comment: @emory - It does not matter that the formality will not be appreciated.  The action itself is what a professional would do.

Comment: How would you say it if you *hadn't* accepted another offer, but their final offer just wasn't good enough?

Comment: @Ramhound I agree that the OP should notify the employer of refusal.  If I was the employer, I would like to be notified as soon as possible so I could get on with business.  How much drafting does "I decline your offer." require? Save your drafting for other things.

Answer (score 1):

Take any good *rejection* letter you received, and invert it to fit. That would do just fine, as long as it's civil and to the point.

You don't need to give justification. You can if you really want and feel the need to, but it's unlikely they will be hurt if you don't, and care if you do. Keep it short and professional.

Answer (score -1):

The ideal solution to me would be to propose another person to substitute you and explain why s/he would be a better fit than you.

---

*a clarification note:*

Why do I say this is the ideal solution?

Because it's a *win-win* situation all three parties - you, the company and the guy you referred.

You *win* double - you may get the respect and appreciation of the company because you did not leave them in the lurch - you offered them a capable guy and you would also most probably *win* admiration from the guy for referring him.

The company *wins* because they are left with an option even though you have declined. And who knows, that guy might be even better than you.

The guy *wins* an opportunity to get a new job or at least an opportunity to get inside view of a company in his field of work.

Of course one may speculate that the company might not accept that suggestion or even deem it disrespectful. The guy might not like the company at all and regret spending time with them. But if you are really confident that the guy and company are a good match for each other, things should take a positive course naturally, unless you are wrong in your judgement. Even in the latter case, this is the ideal thing which you could undertake - and I am talking about the ideal thing you could do, no the ideal thing that could happen.

---

A less than perfect way would be to keep it short as pointed in the first answer. You could Briefly explain why you chose your other alternative over them, if they are smart enough to take advantage of honest feedback.

If they had been a highly preferred alternative in your final decision, you could tell them under what circumstances you would do some occasional or freelance work for them. If they had been far too low on your list just politely inform them of your decision.

Comment: The ideal solution actually would be to simply decline their offer.  You should not be expected to suggest a substitute.  I see no benefit in a suggesting some random person the company doesn't even know.

Comment: I had in mind suggesting another person whom you believe to be at least as good as you, for that job. This is why I included the "and explain why s/he would be a better fit than you" part in my first sentence. Not talking about a random person at all.

I also added a clarification in my answer why I consider my suggestion an ideal solution.