# Turning down a job offer without Burning Bridges

Tags: work-environment, job-search, new-job, job-offer

I have 2 job offers offered in my table. However, how do I decline a job offer without burning bridges? what words should I say or email? it's my first time in the industry and I have no experience on dealing with these kind of issues

Comment: It's like dating: for every 10 offers, you get 9 NO's and only 1 YES... if you're lucky. Trust me, they're used to it. You won't burn bridges by saying "no". Just be very sure before saying anything. Changing your mind afterwards... now that's a problem

Comment: see also [How to decline an already accepted offer, professionally and politely, if I want to accept counteroffer from current employer?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/11219/how-to-decline-an-already-accepted-offer-professionally-and-politely-if-i-want)

Answer (score 18):

Declining an offer because you got another one doesn't burn bridges. This sort of thing burns bridges:

> You call that an offer? Another firm actually knows what I'm worth and I'll be accepting their offer, not your insulting one.
>
> After coming on site and seeing how you people "work" I know for sure I couldn't stand it there. Heaven knows why you think I would. I'm taking a much better offer.

This sort of thing does not:

> I have decided to accept another offer.

You can surround it with thanking them for the opportunity to learn more about them, and praising them for being almost as good as the offer you took. You can tell them "it's not you, it's me" by citing a highly personal reason like geography (the other offer lets me live closer to where my SO is at school) or technology (I am fascinated by space and couldn't resist a chance to work on a project that will go there) if you want, and have something true handy. You can close with the wish your paths will continue to cross. But the heart of the letter, the sentence that matters, is simple, unequivocal, and polite. Build your letter around it.

Comment: +1, ultimately, hiring managers know that if someone is good enough for them to make an offer to, they're good enough for other people to make an offer to as well. You don't need to be over-effusive, just polite. Thank them for their offer, apologize for declining it, that's plenty.

Answer (score 6):

The usual form non-form "Dear John" letter:

1. I have two offers
2. I have to pick one because I can't be in two places at the same time
3. It was a tough choice because both offers are good offers and both companies are good, strong companies
4. I'll have buyer's remorse no matter what choice I make
5. I must now tell you that I am accepting the other offer with plenty of buyer's remorse for not going with you
6. I got to know you and your company thanks to the kind invitation you extended to me for interviews, I got to like both you and your company, and I hope that we get a chance to do business again at some point in the future. I want you to know that you built up quite a bit of good will with me, and I don't want you to feel like you wasted your time interviewing me. Because you didn't.
7. And now, you give the finishing blow: "Again, thank you for everything" :)